# Support for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

Will EOS run on Ubuntu 18.04? In the docs 16.04 is explicitly listed, so am wondering if 18.04 is supported.

Comment: You can at least use it with docker I would guess...

Comment: you're really going bleeding edge there :) 
best to just try it probably. It runs and builds on 17.04 without major issues.

Comment: @expaand If any of the answer to your question is listed below, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've compiled and run it without any problems on Ubuntu 18.04, which is great because it's an LTS.  We're asking for an DEB package (see https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/1021) to make it easier to install. It's planed to be supported in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I've build EOS on 18.04 LTS without any problems, nevertheless I would recommend to use docker, which should be much easier to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18 hasn't introuced any specific change that could break eosio, so of course it works.
All we need is to update the README and add a nice .deb package.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dawn 4.2 release notes](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/dawn-v4.2.0):

> Following last week’s change to the token symbol, we added the ability to specify the core token symbol in the Dockerfile. We also switched to **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** for the Docker builder image.

I have been running a testnet on Ubuntu 18.04 (w/out Docker) and haven't encountered any issues related to OS or version.